# Inserting a single row at the very first start-up in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite database with a table defined in my DataContext class:

```
public DbSet<SystemInfo> SystemInformation { get; set; }
```

This table always contains just a single row with the system information:

```
public class SystemInfo
    {
        public SystemInfo() { }
        [DefaultValue("1")]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public uint NoOfEmailsSentDayily { get; set; }
        public bool autoEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want is to insert an initial row for the table the very first time I run my app. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OnModelCreating` Method to do that

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SystemInfo>().HasData(
        new SystemInfo
        {
            NoOfEmailsSentDayily = 1,
            autoEmail = true
        }
    );
}
```

Or you can create a seeder method that you can call on your `Main` program

```
public class DataSeeder
{
    public static void SeedSystem(DbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.SystemInfo.Any())
        {
            var sysInfo = new SystemInfo
            {
               NoOfEmailsSentDayily = 1,
               autoEmail = true
            }
            context.SystemInfo.Add(sysInfo);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your method

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        DataSeeder.SeedSystem(context);
    }
    host.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you work with DependecyInjection:
One possible solution can be that you write a extendion at app start.

In Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{            
  //...
  app.AutoFill();
  //...
}
```

The Extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{        
  public static IApplicationBuilder AutoFill(this IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
      using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
      var mycontext = scope.ServiceProvider
          .GetRequiredService<IMyDbContext>(); //Insert correct name of db context or db context interface
      if (mycontext.SystemInformation.FirstOrDefault() != null)
      {
          return app;
      }
        
      SystemInformation sysInfo = new();
      //fill SystemInformation
      mycontext.Add(sysInfo);
      mycontext.SaveChanges();
      return app;
  }
}
```